# What is the most general mathematical definition of symmetry?

Tags: definition, transformation, symmetry

I have heard of definitions along the line of saying that a transformation T of something with respect to a certain property p is symmetric if, after T is applied, p remains unchanged. Is there a way of refining this definition? How could you use this definition to show that fractals are symmetric? What are T and p? If something satisfies a recurrence relationship, is that a type of symmetry?

##################################################

From the comments, I am getting the impression that there is no specific definition of mathematical symmetry.
Fractals are frequently described as being highly symmetric. The idea is that you can uniformly contract or expand a fractal and lay it on top of itself.

Comment: "Let $G$ be a group".

Comment: As a dan wrote, group theory is the study of symmetry. Specifically, a group action on a set is the most general definition of symmetry.

Comment: Why do you think that fractals are symmetric?

Comment: All in all, I find this question too unfocused to be answerable. At best, you will get some conflicting opinions.